# Object reference and object showing different result

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I am quite new to the concepts and pretty naive user so please excuse me for the following question,but

I am trying to understand the basic concepts of collection in java

I have made the following class

```
package com.vish;

public class HashSetDemo {
    private int age;

    public HashSetDemo(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Now here I am having set collection framework described in my following class

```
package com.vish;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class HashSetDemo1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashSetDemo hsd = new HashSetDemo(23);
        HashSetDemo hsd1 = new HashSetDemo(24);
        HashSet<HashSetDemo> hashset = new HashSet<HashSetDemo>();
        hashset.add(hsd);
        hashset.add(hsd1);
        System.out.println(hashset.size());
        System.out.println(hashset.contains(hsd));
        System.out.println(hashset.contains(new HashSetDemo(23)));
    }
}
```

Now the outut of this is following

```
2
true
false
```

Why is the last one false,when it has the same object reference

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the last one false,when it has the same object reference

It doesn't. You've created a *new* object which happens to have the same value for `age`.

It's like asking a builder to build you two houses with 5 bedrooms. Yes, they look the same - but they're different houses, with different addresses.

Now `HashSet` actually doesn't for equal *references* - it checks for equal *objects* - where equality is determined via the `hashCode` and `equals` methods. By default, this checks for reference identity, but it doesn't have to. So if you override `equals` and `hashCode` to determine equality just your `age` value, then it would consider your new object equal to the old one.

```
public final class HashSetDemo {
    private final int age;

    public HashSetDemo(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof HashSetDemo)) {
           return false;
        }
        HashSetDemo otherDemo = (HashSetDemo) other;
        return age == otherDemo.age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not implemented `equals()` in your `HashSetDemo` class.  If you don't do that, then java can't figure out how to tell if two objects are equal.  It does have a default implementation though, and that default implementation is to ask, "Are these two objects the same reference?"

Since you are explicitly creating a new `HashSetDemo`, Java uses the default `equals()` and says, "no, these are not the same instance of `HashSetDemo`"

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not provided a custom equals and hashCode method for your class. Your class uses the implementations provided by Object.

If you overrode equals to be `return this.age == ((HashSetDemo)other).age` and overrode hashCode to return a hash value derived from age, then your last call to hashset.contains would return True.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the same reference. In second case, you are creating new instance of `HashSetDemo`, and that has different address in memory.

Your `HashSet` is using default comparator for searching, and that compares instances of objects, not their content.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the last one false,when it has the same object reference

Even though the objects are exactly the same, they aren't the same objects. It's like putting one brand new bicycle in a garage, getting another brand new bicycle exactly the same as the other, and asking the garage if it contains the second bike. Sure, the bikes may be *equal*, but they're not *the same*.

Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals() and hashCode() in HashSetDemo. This tells your program how to determine whether 2 separate instances are equal. If you don't, your program will fall back to the default implementation, which only checks the object reference. In your third line, the object is equivalent, but Java doesn't know that - it only knows that its a different reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the last case you have created `new Object` `new HashSetDemo(23)` It will store in different location in the `java heap memory`. It is different compare to the other two objects `hsd and hsd1`.